# How can I prevent UITextfield from auto sizing based on the content?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield

How can I prevent UITextfield from auto sizing based on the content without giving an explicit width?

Answer (score 0):

You could give it an explicit size without giving it an explicit *width* per se. For example, you could give it size constraints relative to another element's size, or relative to the screen's size, etc. There's all kinds of unique constraints to explore.